# SVN pre-commit hook for java code compilation

Tags: java, svn, version-control, svn-hooks, pre-commit

This sounds to me difficult but ensuring, if it is possible to add server or local svn pre-commit hook to prevent if there are any java code compilations. Usually when there is a requirement to merge bulk of java files from higher version to lower version, and if we do not have working local lower env setup, then this mechanism will help to save time setting up the local env.

- Just thinking a solution - If I have a running QA AIX box of lower env, that I can utilize for code compilation while doing the checkins, in the hook I can add command  as `javac -classpath <AIX path>:$CLASSPATH:<corresponding jar> -d . filename.java`, where filename.java will be passed as parameter. Along with connection credentials so that I can first connect to AIX before to compile. Is this approach possible, if yes how to add such conditions in hook. Or is there any thing already available that I am not aware of ?

Comment: Are you using a CI solution like Jenkins or something similar? Furthermore do you use a build system like Maven, Gradle etc. ? Do you have unit/integration tests?

Comment: Yes, I am using Jenkins for build and deployment the code on AIX box using Maven. So generally all developers check in the code concurrently, first it kick off the SNAPSHOT maven build and failed if there are compilation found, so want to avoid, if we can add hook to compile before to start SNAPSHOT, so each individual developer can take care during check in the code, rather after the snapshot failed

Comment: What is the problem with a failing build in particular if you have a SNAPSHOT build? The dev receives an email saying there is something wrong and will be fixed. That's it...Furthermore in you have compilation failures you should train the devs to use their IDE to check first or even better build locally before committing...another thing best would be using branches for each task/dev so it's not really an issue an trunk is always being fine...Furthermore if you would do a pre-commit hook you need to compile the whole project which takes too long until the commiter will get an feedback.

Comment: and in the end it will prevent devs from committing their code..which is really bad...